# GitHub action dynamic secrets among multiple jobs

Tags: github, github-actions, vault

We have a CD pipeline which retrieves secrets from our Vault. Currently our action has multiple calls to the vault action for each job in the workflow. I want to make it cleaner so it calls it once in a job and uses the secret among all the jobs.

Our current workflow looks like this:

```
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ${{ inputs.runner_environment }}
    steps:
      - name: Retrieve secrets
        uses: /workflows/actions/vault@v1
        with:
          namespace: ${{ inputs.vault_namespace }}
          auth_method: ${{ inputs.vault_auth_method }}
          role_id: ${{ secrets.vault_role_id }}
          secret_id: ${{ secrets.vault_secret_id }}
          auth_role: ${{ inputs.vault_auth_role }}
          auth_path: ${{ inputs.vault_auth_path }}
          secrets: |
            ${{ inputs.artifactory_username_vault_secret_path }} ${{ inputs.artifactory_username_vault_secret_key }} | ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME;
            ${{ inputs.artifactory_password_vault_secret_path }} ${{ inputs.artifactory_password_vault_secret_key }} | ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD;


      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Verify
        uses: /workflows/actions/verify_quarkus@v1
        with:
          maven_settings_path: ${{ inputs.maven_settings_path }}
          artifactory_username: ${{ env.ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME }}
          artifactory_password: ${{ env.ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD }}

  docker_image:
    name: Build & Push Docker image
    runs-on: ${{ inputs.runner_environment }}
    needs: build
    outputs:
      tag: ${{ steps.docker_image.outputs.tag }}
      image_full_path: ${{ steps.docker_image.outputs.image_full_path }}
    steps:
      - name: Retrieve secrets
        uses: /workflows/actions/vault@v1
        with:
          namespace: ${{ inputs.vault_namespace }}
          auth_method: ${{ inputs.vault_auth_method }}
          role_id: ${{ secrets.vault_role_id }}
          secret_id: ${{ secrets.vault_secret_id }}
          auth_role: ${{ inputs.vault_auth_role }}
          auth_path: ${{ inputs.vault_auth_path }}
          secrets: |
            ${{ inputs.artifactory_username_vault_secret_path }} ${{ inputs.artifactory_username_vault_secret_key }} | ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME;
            ${{ inputs.artifactory_password_vault_secret_path }} ${{ inputs.artifactory_password_vault_secret_key }} | ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD;
      - name: Download artifacts
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: artifacts
      - name: Build & Push Docker image
        uses: /workflows/actions/docker_image@v1
        id: docker_image
        with:
          image_name: ${{ inputs.docker_image_name }}
          artifactory_registry: ${{ inputs.artifactory_registry }}
          artifactory_repository: ${{ inputs.artifactory_repository }}
          artifactory_username: ${{ env.ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME }}
          artifactory_password: ${{ env.ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD }}
```

As you can imagine there are way more jobs inside but I trimmed it. I want to have a separate job called retieve-vault and use it's outputs in every other job but so far I couldn't manage it. Last thing I tried is:

```
vault:
    name: Retrieve Vault Secrets
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME: ${{ steps.set_outputs.outputs.ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME }}
      ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD: ${{ steps.set_outputs.outputs.ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD }}
    steps:
      - name: Retrieve Vault Secrets
        uses: /workflows/actions/vault@v1
        id: vault
        with:
          namespace: ${{ inputs.vault_namespace }}
          auth_method: ${{ inputs.vault_auth_method }}
          role_id: ${{ secrets.vault_role_id }}
          secret_id: ${{ secrets.vault_secret_id }}
          auth_role: ${{ inputs.vault_auth_role }}
          auth_path: ${{ inputs.vault_auth_path }}
          secrets: |
            ${{ inputs.artifactory_username_vault_secret_path }} ${{ inputs.artifactory_username_vault_secret_key }} | ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME;
            ${{ inputs.artifactory_password_vault_secret_path }} ${{ inputs.artifactory_password_vault_secret_key }} | ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD;

      - name: Set outputs
        id: set_outputs
        run: |
          echo "ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME=${{ env.ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME }}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT;
          echo "ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD=${{ env.ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD }}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT;
```

And use it like ${{ needs.vault.outputs.ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME }} but it doesn't work as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your separate job looks fine and the syntax to access the output too. What do you by that "it doesn't work"? Did you try verifying the retrieved secrets by printing those in a separate step?

Comment: @Azeem In the docker login action, I am getting an error saying `Username and password required`. Also in the logs of the run, I see it's not being passed to the action.

Comment: Please include your docker login step in your question. I believe the first part of your question your existing consolidated workflow. You need to add the rest of the updated workflow with `vault` as a separate job.

Comment: @Azeem docker login step is an internal step in the official docker_image action.